How to Accurately Update and Use a Variable in Unity with a Power Meter Style Animation?
I'm working on a fishing game in Unity where I need to set the number of fish caught (fishAmount) based on the player's interaction with different colored areas (Green, Red, LightGreen, Orange). The key part here is that the interaction happens through an arrow that moves back and forth over a power meter-like UI element, indicating different levels of success.
I'm using the OnTriggerStay2D method to detect which colored area the arrow is over, and I update the fishAmount variable accordingly. However, when I call the ClickDeck method to finalize the action, fishAmount often holds the wrong value.
Here's the full code for reference:
using DG.Tweening;
using Dreamteck.Splines;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class FishinDeckController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject deck;
    public Animation _animation;
    public GameObject perfectText;
    public GameObject goodText;
    public GameObject notBadText;
    public PlayerFishingController playerFishingController;
    public static int fishAmount = 0;
    public GameObject fishPrefab;
    public Animator playerAnimator;
    public Transform fishParent;
    public Transform firstStackPos;
    public Transform stackParent;
    public PlayerInteractController PlayerInteractController;
    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (!_animation.enabled)
        {
            if (other.CompareTag("Green"))
            {
                perfectText.SetActive(true);
                fishAmount = 3;
            }
            else if (other.CompareTag("Red"))
            {
                notBadText.SetActive(true);
                fishAmount = 1;
            }
            else if (other.CompareTag("LightGreen"))
            {
                goodText.SetActive(true);
                fishAmount = 2;
            }
            else if (other.CompareTag("Orange"))
            {
                notBadText.SetActive(true);
                fishAmount = 1;
            }
        }
    }


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        deck.GetComponent<RectTransform>().DOScale(new Vector3(1, 1, 1), 1f).SetEase(Ease.Flash);
        _animation.enabled = true;
        perfectText.SetActive(false);
        goodText.SetActive(false);
        notBadText.SetActive(false);
    }
 

    public IEnumerator DeckCloser()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
        deck.GetComponent<RectTransform>().DOScale(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 1f).SetEase(Ease.Flash).OnComplete(() =>
        {
            deck.SetActive(false);
        });
    }


    public void FishingDeckOpener()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        playerFishingController.isPlayerFishing = true;
    }



    public void CatchFish(int fishAmount)
    {
        playerAnimator.SetBool("didFishCame", true);

        StartCoroutine(CatchFishCoroutine(fishAmount));
    }
    private IEnumerator CatchFishCoroutine(int fishAmount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fishAmount + 1; i++)
        {
            Transform fishTransform = fishParent.transform.GetChild(i);

            // SplineFollower'� devre d��� b�rak
            fishTransform.GetComponent<SplineFollower>().enabled = false;

            // Yeni bal�k instantiate et ve pozisyonunu ayarla
            GameObject newFish = Instantiate(fishPrefab, fishTransform.position, fishTransform.rotation);
            newFish.transform.SetParent(fishParent);

            // Stack Parent'ta bulunan �ocuk say�s�n� al
            int childCount = stackParent.transform.childCount;

            // E�er stack limiti dolmam��sa bal��� stack'e ekle
            if (childCount < PlayerInteractController.playerCarryLimit)
            {
                float startYPosition = 0f;
                float newYPosition = startYPosition + 0.35f * childCount;
                Vector3 newLocalPosition = new Vector3(0, newYPosition, 0);

                // Bal��� stack listesine ekle
                PlayerInteractController.stack.Add(newFish);

                // Orijinal global scale'i sakla
                Vector3 originalGlobalScale = newFish.transform.lossyScale;

                // Yeni parent'� ayarla
                newFish.transform.SetParent(stackParent.transform, true);

                // Orijinal global scale'i yeniden uygula
                newFish.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                    originalGlobalScale.x / stackParent.transform.lossyScale.x,
                    originalGlobalScale.y / stackParent.transform.lossyScale.y,
                    originalGlobalScale.z / stackParent.transform.lossyScale.z
                );

                // Bal��� yeni pozisyona ta��
                yield return newFish.transform.DOLocalMove(newLocalPosition, 0.2f).OnComplete(() =>
                {
                    // Hareket tamamland�ktan sonra rotasyonu s�f�rla
                    newFish.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                }).WaitForCompletion();

                // BoxCollider'� devre d��� b�rak

                // Event g�nder

                // E�er stack limiti dolmu�sa fullText'i g�ster
                if (PlayerInteractController.stack.Count == PlayerInteractController.playerCarryLimit)
                {
                    float fullTextYPosition = startYPosition + 0.35f * (childCount + 1); // childCount + 1 yeni �ocu�u da hesaba katmak i�in
                    Vector3 fullTextPosition = new Vector3(0, fullTextYPosition, 0);

                    // fullText g�sterme i�lemleri burada yap�labilir
                }
            }

            // Mevcut bal��� devre d��� b�rak (�sterseniz yok edebilirsiniz)
            // Destroy(fishTransform.gameObject); // Alternatif: Bal��� yok et

            // Her bal�k hareketinden sonra bir s�re bekle (�rne�in 0.1 saniye)
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }

    public void ClickDeck()
    {
        _animation.enabled = false;
        CatchFish(fishAmount);
        StartCoroutine(DeckCloser());
    }
}


The main issue is that fishAmount doesn't always hold the correct value when ClickDeck() is called. I suspect that the OnTriggerStay2D method is either not updating fishAmount correctly or that the arrow's movement across the power meter causes the value to change unexpectedly.
How can I ensure that fishAmount is correctly set according to the arrow's position on the power meter when the player clicks to proceed? Are there any best practices or different approaches to handle this scenario?
To achieve this, I used the OnTriggerStay2D method to detect which colored area the arrow is over, and then update the fishAmount variable accordingly. My approach was to update fishAmount every time the arrow is within a specific colored area, expecting that when the player clicks to lock in their selection (ClickDeck method), the fishAmount would reflect the correct value based on the arrow's position.
I expected that by using OnTriggerStay2D, the fishAmount would be accurately set to the correct value based on where the arrow stopped when the player clicked. However, this isn't happening consistently. Sometimes fishAmount reflects a different value than what I expected based on the arrow's final position on the meter.

What does the Animation do? It would be more convenient to use Animator instead of Animation. The first thing that comes to mind is that you have some value on the Animation itself, that changes and overrides the value.

Why use physics? Shouldn't this usually be a time-based animation?

Im using animation because it is more optimized than the animator

Using the presentation (UI arrow) as a model is not really a good idea, especially by piling up the physics (trigger detection) on top of it. You already have a function that makes the arrow go back and forth, use its result (say, from 0 to 1) in the moment of user click to place a 'dice roll' in one of the 'buckets'. Each bucket is defined by boundaries, like 0..0.4, 0.4..0.6, 0.6..1 and returns the value you assigned to the 'colored areas' of your gauge.
